# Pasar datos de un formulario a otro en HTML

Tags: php, html

Consiste en dos paginas donde la pagina 1 introduce información en un campo y después le damos al botón y este te dirige a un formulario, donde ya tienes escrito un campo con la información antes escrita

Esta es la pagina de inicio, quiero que el input cedula se pase al otro formulario

```
<form method="POST" action="Registro/Registrar.php">
    <table border="3" width="50%" >

         <tr><td><center>Cedula: <input type="text" name="Cedula">
         <input type="submit" value="Insertar">
         </center></td></tr>

     </table>
</form>
```

El campo que quiero que ya tenga la información del formulario anterior, lo voy a resaltar entre ** para que lo puedan ver en el código de abajo

```
<table  bordercolor="#003D79" border = "3" style = "margin: 0 auto:" width="75%">
 <th> <font size="6" color="#FF2D2D"> Formulario AcroBiolab </font> </th> </table>

<br>
<form id="formal" name = "formal" method = "POST" action = "insertar Registro.php">
<table bordercolor="#003D79" border = "3" style = "margin: 0 auto:" width="75%">

<th colspan="4" bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Infromacion del cliente </th><tr></tr>


**<input type="hidden" name="Cedula">** --Este el input que tenga la información del código anterior



<tr><td bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Nombre:     </td><td><input type="text" name="Nombre" maxlength="30"> </td>
    <td bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Apellido:   </td><td><input type="text" name="Apellido" maxlength="30" required></td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Edad:       </td><td><input type="text" name="Edad" maxlength="3" required></td> 
    <td bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Sexo:       </td><td><input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="Masculino" required> Masculino
                                                <input type="radio" name="Sexo" value="Femenino"  required> Femenino</tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#97CBFF">Telefono:</td><td>
<select name="Telefono" required>
 <option value = "0212"> 0212 </option>
 <option value = "0412"> 0412 </option>
 <option value = "0414"> 0414 </option>
 <option value = "0424"> 0424 </option>
 <option value = "0416"> 0416 </option>
 <option value = "0426"> 0426 </option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="Numero" size="12" required></td>
<td bgcolor="#97CBFF"> Extra: </td><td><input type="text" name="Extra" maxlength="30" required></td>

<tr><td bgcolor="#97CBFF">Direccion:  </td><td><input type="text" name="Direccion"   required></td>
    <td bgcolor="#97CBFF">Observacion:</td><td><input type="text" name="Observacion"></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"> <center> <input type="reset"  value="Limpiar"  id="Limpiar"/> 
    <td colspan="2"> <center> <input type="submit" value="Registro" id="Registro"/></tr> 

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con recibir el dato que te llega en `$_POST['Cedula']` y asignárselo al `value` del `input` oculto... Algo así:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Cedula" value="<?php echo $_POST['Cedula'] ?>">
```

O de una forma un poco mas limpia:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Cedula" value="<?= $_POST['Cedula'] ?>">
```